# Trying to delete an Azure blob - getting blob does not exist exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure storage container with blobs (/images/filename). The filename(uri) is stored in the database at creation time and comes from the file upload save function:

```
        blob.UploadFromStream(filestream);
        string uri = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        return uri;
```

The file upload works fine and when passes to the client with SAS key download works fine too.

Coming to delete the images I have a helper function that was taken from a MS example here:[MS Github example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-Storage-DotNet/Controllers/HomeController.cs)
Here is the function:

```
    internal bool DeleteFile(string fileURI)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(fileURI);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
            CloudBlockBlob fileblob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
            fileblob.Delete();
            bool res = fileblob.DeleteIfExists();
            return res; //Ok
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

This is all in a helper class which starts as follows:

```
public class AzureHelpers
{
    private string connection;
    private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    private CloudBlobClient blobClient;
    private CloudBlobContainer container;


    public AzureHelpers()
    {
        connection = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("myproject_AzureStorageConnectionString");
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connection);
        blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Resources.DataStoreRoot);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
 ....
```

I deliberately added the delete before the deleteIfExists to cause the exception and prove what I suspected that it wasn't finding the file/blob.

As I step through the code however, the CloudBlockBlob is definitely there and has the correct URI etc.

I am wondering if this could be a permissions thing? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a directory in your container. Assume that you have a container named `container_1`, and your files are stored in directory like `/images/a.jpg`. Here you should remember that in this case, your blob name is `images/a.jpg`, not `a.jpg`.

In your code, `Path.GetFileName` only get the file name like `a.jpg`, so it does not match the real blob name `images/a.jpg`, which cause the error "does not exist".

So in your `DeleteFile(string fileURI)` method, try the code below, it works fine at my side:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(fileURI);
var temp = uri.LocalPath;
string filename = temp.Remove(0, temp.IndexOf('/', 1)+1);
CloudBlockBlob fileblob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
//fileblob.Delete();
bool res = fileblob.DeleteIfExists();
```

or use this code snippet:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(fileURI);

//use this line of code just to get the blob name correctly
CloudBlockBlob blob_temp = new CloudBlockBlob(uri);

var myblob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob_temp.Name);
bool res = myblob.DeleteIfExists();
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan, that was it. I had indeed got Images in there as a sub-folder. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a permission issue, Can you goto portal and then  Edit container meta data on azure bolb storage. change access private to **`public`**.

Comment: Ok I can do that in the morning my time, but if that works, showing it is an access issue, how do I do it from the server call. I dont want to leave it set to public..? Do I use a SAS key appended to the URI? Or?

Comment: I don't think setting container to public can help, since public container can only allow anonymous read operations against blobs, anonymous delete operations against blobs or container are not allowed. In addition, Brett is already using connection string to construct the client, which is supposed to have full permissions.